# implement a deterministic distribution in java

Tags: java

I've made the following code for a binomial distribution, can somebody tell me how I can do the same for a deterministic distribution ( this distribution has to generate the same number all the time ) It is supposed to be the most easy distribution, but I cant find a 'DeterministicDistribution' is the library.

thanks for your help.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.AbstractIntegerDistribution;
import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.BinomialDistribution;

public class Binomial extends Distribution
{
    AbstractIntegerDistribution distribution;



    @Override
    public void setParameters(HashMap<String,?> hm)
    {
    try
    {
         int n = 0;
         double p =0.0;
            if (hm.containsKey("n"))
                n = Integer.parseInt((String) hm.get("n"));
            else
                throw new Exception("Exception: No n-value found");
                    if(hm.containsKey("p"))
                         p = Double.parseDouble((String) hm.get("p"));
                    else
                        throw new Exception("Exception: No p-value found");
        distribution = new BinomialDistribution(n,p);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    }


    @Override
    public int getSample()
   {
       int a = distribution.sample();
       return a;
   }  

    public AbstractIntegerDistribution getDistribution() 
    {
        return distribution;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is an existing library for this, but one way to do it is to use the constructor

```
public Random(long seed)
```

as this returns an instance of `Random` that is determined by the seed alone.

```
public static int binomialObservation(long seed, int n, double p) {
    if (n < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    if (p <= 0 || n == 0)
        return 0;
    if (p >= 1)
        return n;
    Random random = new Random(seed);
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (random.nextDouble() <= p)
            count++;
    return count;
}
```

As long as you pass the same seed, you will get the same outcome. If you want a sequence of observations, you can increase `seed` by `1` each time you call the method.

If `n` is large, this method will be slow. I don't know how you can do it in constant time. Perhaps you can look at the source code for a non-deterministic binomial observation, and adapt it by using the `Random` constructor taking a seed.